# WebSocket binary transmission returns more data than server sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I have an issue with receiving binary data over WebSocket where the number of bytes received by the browser (in form of ArrayBuffer, in JavaScript) is higher than what the server sent, even though Chrome or Firefox report correctly how many bytes were transmitted over the wire.

The server side is Node JS, and I have used 3 different packages (ws, nodejs-websocket and websocket) and they all behave the same. So it's likely that the issue is in JavaScript running in the browser.

My code on the client side looks like this:

```
1: var socket = new Websocket(url);
2: socket.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';
3: socket.onmessage = function(event) {
4:     var buffer = new Uint8Array(event.data);
5:     // consume the buffer
6: }
```

The problem is that if I examine the length of the "buffer" (after line 4), it's higher than the data sent from the server.

For example, if server sends the binary content, 8 bytes:

```
0xa1 0xb2 0xc3 0xd4 0xa1 0xb2 0xc3 0xd4
```

on the client side, I see:

```
0xc2 0xa1 0xc2 0xb2 0xc3 0x83 0xc3 0x94 0xc2 0xa1 0xc2 0xb2 0xc3 0x83 0xc3 0x94
```

**UPDATE:** after further examination, I believe this has to do with word alignment of the data in memory. For example, if I send the following data: **0x7C 0x7D 0x7E 0x7F**, it's received correctly. But as soon as I consume higher bits, like **0x81**, the **0xc2** gets added to the data.

I can't believe that I have to deal with this! Perhaps I am doing something wrong, but I did look at other frameworks for transferring binary data over websocket and, in fact, they are "unpacking" the real data out of a word-aligned array buffer.

**UPDATE 2:** For completion purposes, this is what's happening on the server, using NodeJS package [websocket](https://www.npmjs.com/package/websocket), where *conn* is the web socket connection obtained from the *websocket* package.

```
function sendBinary(conn, filename) {
    var size = 4096;
    var inputStream = fs.createReadStream(
        filename,
        {
            'flags': 'r',
            'encoding': 'binary',
            'bufferSize': size
        });
    inputStream.on('data', function(data) {
        conn.sendBytes(new Buffer(data));
    });
}
```

Thank you for taking the time to read this. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When print or write stream, make sure to use the original buffer stream, not the string.
In your case you may outprint string instead of buffer.
buf.toString() use encode UTF-8 as default, and Chinese character in UTF-8 takes 3bytes， and then you get unexpected bytes.

By the way, 0xa1 is where the Chinese character starts

Please use [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite)
to convert string to buffer if you need

Or refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40657873/readable-and-writable-streams-unexpected-behavior/40659611#40659611) to combine binary buffer in server side

Comment: This is dealing with binary data (like audio and image data), not Strings, which I think of "binary" + character encoding. The hex values I chose are randomly chosen and have nothing to do with character set.  But thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: Could you please paste your server side code? Just make sure binary buffer cannot simply join each other by using "+", which will convert binary to string

Comment: I have added the server side code to the original post, for completion purposes.

Comment: "new Buffer(data)" is actually working like "new Buffer(data, 'utf-8')" by default. So you need directly send binary like 
`conn.sendBytes(data);`
 Or use  `new Buffer(data, 'binary')` instead.

Comment: You nailed it!!!! That was the problem. Thank you so so so very much. It didn't occur to me to question the server side because both Chrome and Firefox reported the number of bytes received equal to what I expected. But perhaps that's how they count the "bytes" by taking encoding into account. Again, THANK YOU!