# Readable and writable streams unexpected behavior

Tags: node.js, stream

I run into unexpected behavior with regards to `fs.createReadStream` and `fs.createWriteStream`. I hope somebody can point out where I make the wrong assumptions:

I create a readable and writable stream like this

```
let readableStream = fs.createReadStream('./lorem ipsum.doc');
let writableStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output');
```

Why, if I send the read stream to the write stream like this

```
let data, chunk;
readableStream
.on('readable', () => {
    while ((chunk=stream.read()) !== null) {
        data+=chunk;
    }
})
.on('end', ()=>{
    writableStream.write(data)
    console.log("done");
});
```

I end up with a **discrepancy** in the output file:

[image: Output file with discrepancy]

while if I stream like this:

```
let data, chunk;
readableStream
.on('readable', () => {
    while ((chunk=stream.read()) !== null) {
        writableStream.write(chunk)
    }
})
.on('end', ()=>{
    console.log("done");
});
```

all is fine and as expected:

[image: Expected output]

I.e., in the first example, when/where is the additional overhead in bytes added? Why is it added? What goes wrong?

Thanks for enlightening me!

---

*Note:* I am aware of using `pipe` (which gives me the correct output file), but these examples are just for my understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing the point is in the first demo, you use 'data +=', which converts binary stream to character string, and wastes some space. Could you please try to convert the second demo too? ===>

```
var s=chunk;  
writableStream.write(s);
```

Updated: the correct way to combine stream buffer is like your comment:

```
var chunks = [];
var size = 0;
...on('data', function(chunk){
    chunks.push(chunk);
    size += chunk.length;
})
...on('end', function(){
    var buf = Buffer.concat(chunks, size); // use buf to write to writestream
    var str = iconv.decode(buf, 'utf8');   // use str to console.log string, which supports all languages such as Asian
})
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. If I do `let data = Buffer.from([]);`, and then use `data = Buffer.concat([data,chunk]);`, the file comes out right. Stupid of me, I didn't realize I was converting to string type.

Comment: Or actually, that javascript was converting to string type... :)